# Size of .ASPXAUTH

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication

I have a website that uses Forms Authentication (built-in code that came with VS2010 ASP.NET Razor project template). Many of my pages make AJAX (via jQuery's $.ajax) calls to the web site.

I noticed that in secure sections of my site, .ASPXAUTH cookie is sent with each request, which is exactly what I want. But, I also noticed that the size of this cookie is 285 bytes. That's 1/4 Kb on every request.

My intention is to make these AJAX calls as fast as possible, and it sounds like it's too much overhead just to indicate that somebody is logged in.

Is there any way to decrease the size of .ASPXAUTH? Is there a way to provide my own shorter cookie that's "understood" by the Form Authentication infrastructure?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The contents of this are an encrypted Forms Authentication Ticket -- see:

- [FormsAuthenticationTicket Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthenticationticket.aspx)
- [Understanding the Forms Authentication Ticket and Cookie](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/910443)

The size reflects the contents as well as the encryption overhead.  I suppose some different crypto routines would yield different cookie sizes but I don't think I'd trade security for a few bytes.

The cookie needs to be passed because your AJAX calls need to be authenticated.  For things like images you can serve them from another domain (cookieless domain) like static.mydomain.com (instead of www.mydomain.com) and these requests will not have the cookie.